# Meteor Build does not make public folder

Tags: meteor, build

I am building my app using meteor build /directory_path
 it doses not give any error but when its process complete then the app.tar.gz does not have any public folder and does not have any forms/html pages which I have created in app.

my app directory is like this
 client/templets/home/other directories
 this directory have my html forms and js files

other directory such as /lib have js files that should accessed by client and server both
 /public have images foder
 /server have js code that should run on server

help me.
 what should I do

Comment: Not sure what is the problem, after running the bundled app, you cannot access assets that are in the public folder from the browser?

Comment: @adam Wolski yes .. I am uploading the bundle on azure cloud machine using this procedure https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/meteor/ownserver/apache/oss/vivid/deploy_app.html after end of point 3.2 when I try to execute 'sudo apache2ctl restart' command it gives 'AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/app/bundle/public] does not exist
AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app.conf:
Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'restart' failed.'

Comment: I would di it differently, I would set up a reverse proxy to running node.js app

Answer (score 3):

I found all the files in my public folder at

```
bundle/programs/web.browser/app/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem following that same site's walkthrough for installing on Ubuntu 12.04.

Referring to another walkthrough: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial

it directs you to create the public directory yourself, as well as a tmp directory at the root of your app directory on the host. So you essentially end up with:

```
myapp/bundle
myapp/public
myapp/tmp
```

and of course you will have to edit the virtual host document root line to reflect that location. This worked to get things up and running for me.