# What is the use for the special "public" folder in a Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm currently using Meteor and trying to learn more about the framework. In the [documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) about special directories the following is said about the `public/` special directory:

> All files inside a top-level directory called `public/` are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include `public/` in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference `public/bg.png` as `<img src='/bg.png' />`. This is the best place for `favicon.ico`, `robots.txt`, and similar files.

My question is: since I refer to files inside of `public/` directory as if they were located in the root folder of my application, what's the different between putting the files in the `public/` folder and in the root folder? Or is it just for organization sake?

Also the documentation I quoted above makes some examples using assets (some pngs and `favicon.ico`) and no JavaScript or HTML files. Am I able to put some JavaScript code in there and then import them in another file by referencing as if this code was located in the root of my app? Or is the `public/` directory somewhat made only for assets?

I failed to find any docs that explains what is done to files inside this directory in detail (I only found what I quoted above). So if any documentation of that kind is available it would help a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: since I refer to files inside of public/ directory as if they were located in the root folder of my application, what's the different between putting the files in the public/ folder and in the root folder? Or is it just for organization sake?

Just because you can reference or "import" a file from `public/` doesn't mean it functions in the same way to how a normal file import would work. Files located in `public` gets served as is without being minified/run through the Meteor pipleline. Second, these files are accessible to the client which makes sense given how'd import them without preceding slashes and keep them mostly to serve stuff like favicon and what not.

So in a sense, such files within `public` are made available within relation to your client bundle/code whilst not being a part of them, get it?

This way of serving assets isn't unique to Meteor, even React has a [public directory](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

> Also the documentation I quoted above makes some examples using assets (some pngs and favicon.ico) and no JavaScript or HTML files. Am I able to put some JavaScript code in there and then import them in another file by referencing as if this code was located in the root of my app? Or is the public/ directory somewhat made only for assets?

AFAIK, you can have files of any type in `public` but since

- It's served as is to the client, meaning it's exposed to the public
- It doesn't get minified (i.e being part of the final application build code)

You're advised to not have any of the application code within this directory.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give more details (maybe a link to a documentation) about this "Meteor pipeline"? Maybe there's some more relevant information there about the process you described. Feel free to edit your answer with that if you find relevant.

Comment: It would also help to know where you got this information from.

Comment: https://guide.meteor.com/v1.3/build-tool.html#minification
https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger:-Meteor-tutorial#prepare-your-app
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41525930/6688795

Answer (score 0):

The `Public` folder is how you serve your static files, when you put a file in your root folder it will not be sent to the client by default and you can't use it in your css, when you put that file (say an image) in your `public` folder you can use it from the css and refer to it as if it was in your root folder, so if I put `a.jpg` in the `public` folder I can use `url(/a.jpg)` in my css, that won't work if `a.jpg` is simply in your root folder, that's what the docs mean when they say it's served as if it was the root folder.

Comment: As far as I know every file outside Meteor's special directories are loaded for the client and for the server by default. That's why there is the `import` directory. Is it different for files that are not code?

Answer (score -2):

unlike in Rails, Meteor initiatives don’t have a rigid document structure and you are quite a whole lot free to prepare your projects as you want. a few folder names but have unique which means, and documents within them will be dealt with in a different way.
consumer
files here will be loaded at the client simplest. files in that folder don’t need things like Meteor.isClient.

**server**
Loaded on the server best, duh! No need for Meteor.isServer whilst files are in that folder, the client won’t see these files.
**public**
This directory is for property like photographs. on your initiatives, you reference stuff in the public folder as if they have been in the root folder. as an example, when you have a report: public/nude.jpg, then for your app you include it with .
**personal**
files only available at the server facet thru the assets API.
**checks**
documents in there received’t be loaded anywhere and are used for checking out your app.
**lib**
documents in that folder are loaded earlier than whatever else, which makes it the best listing to vicinity the distinct libraries used on a undertaking.

Comment: Hey thanks for your time but I had some problems understanding your answer. You said what I already know about the `public` directory: You can put assets there and you reference them as if they were in the root folder. But you didn't answer the questions I made.